# Ballistic Motion, unable to retrieve required angle formula

Tags: projectile

I am trying to retrieve the motion for the required angle for a ballistic flight. Given the equation

$$y = \tan(\theta) x - \frac{g}{2v_0^2\cos^2\theta}x^2$$

which describes the projectile motion, I would like to "restructure" the formula to be able to get the angle theta for given velocity, x and y values. 
From wikipedia I know again, that the formula should be:

$$\tan\theta = \frac{v^2 \pm \sqrt{v^4-g(gx^2+2yv^2)}}{gx}$$

But i would really like to know how I get from the first formula to the second one.. All my attempts have gotten me to a point where i couldn't solve it anymore ($x\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta) - y\cos^2(\theta) = gx^2 / 2 / v^2$).

Any hint in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: Please be specific: (1) Define the angle, e.g.  $tan(\theta) = y/x$. (2) State your initial conditions.  (3) Link your references, such that people can look them up. (4) Try to use MathJax for your formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{\cos^2\theta} = \sec^2\theta = 1 + \tan^2\theta$$

Comment: Please, can you put a detail explanation of the your answer? I have voted positive and I am very glad. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Sebastiano After making this substitution, every $\theta$ appears as part of a $\tan\theta$ expression. This way, you can treat $\tan\theta$ as a variable-like unit and solve the equation for it.

Comment: Yes Yes....You have right. Last night...I was very tired....excuse me....I have appreciated much your contibute.